# Generating nested XML through Oracle XML Functions

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

I am trying to generate a nested XML taking data from HR schema in Oracle. The XML should look like below. The data, in this case, resides in Oracle PLSQL objects and not in employees and departments table.

```
<Departments>
   <department id = "department_id" name = "department_name" >
         <employees>
             <employee id = "employee_id">
                 <employee_name> </employee_name>
                 <salary> </salary>
             </employee>
             <employee id = "employee_id">
                 <employee_name> </employee_name>
                 <salary> </salary>
             </employee>
         </employees>
   </department>
 </Departments>
```

The objects can be created using below code:

```
--Employee Object 
CREATE TYPE emp_o AS OBJECT (
    employee_id     NUMBER,
    employee_name   VARCHAR2(100),
    salary          NUMBER
);

--Employee table

CREATE TYPE emp_ot IS
    TABLE OF emp_o;
--Department object

CREATE TYPE deps_o AS OBJECT (
    department_id     NUMBER,
    department_name   VARCHAR2(100),
    emp_tab           emp_ot
);
--department table

CREATE TYPE deps_t IS
    TABLE OF deps_o;
```

Here is what I have tried so far, below code does the following-
1. Populate PLSQL objects
2. Generate XML Clob using data in those objects. --> Here I am facing problem. Please consider only **uncommented code**

```
DECLARE 
  l_message DEPS_T;
  l_employee_t emp_ot;
  l_xml_clob CLOB;
BEGIN 
  SELECT deps_o(
           d.department_id,
           d.department_name,
           emp_ot(emp_o(
                        e.employee_id,
                        e.first_name || ' ' || e.last_name,
                        e.salary
                       )
                  )
           )
  BULK COLLECT INTO l_message 
  FROM   departments d , employees e
  where  e.department_id = d.department_id and d.department_id =20; 
  --Print the content 
--  for i in 1..l_message.COUNT 
--  loop
--        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_message(i).department_id);
--        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_message(i).department_name);
--        l_employee_t := l_message(i).emp_tab;
--        for j in 1..l_employee_t.COUNT
--        loop
--            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Employee Name:'||l_employee_t(j).employee_name);
--        end loop;
--  end loop;

  --Generate XML
--  <Departments>
--    <department id = "department_id" name = "department_name" >
--          <employees>
    --          <employee id = "employee_id">
        --          <employee_name> </employee_name>
        --          <salary> </salary>
    --          </employee>
--          </employees>
--    </department>
--  </Departments>

--  select XMlelement("Departments",XMLElement("department",
--                   XMLAttributes(t.department_name as "id", t.department_name as "name"),
--                   XMLElement("employees",
--                               XMLElement("employee",
--                                           XMLAttributes(g.employee_id as "employee_id"),
--                                           XMLForest(g.employee_name,g.salary)
--                                         )
--                             )
--                   
--                   )).getClobval() into l_xml_clob
--    
--  from  TABLE(CAST(l_message as deps_t)) t,
--        TABLE(CAST(t.emp_tab as emp_ot)) g;

select XMLELEMENT("Departments",
                   (SELECT XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("department",
                   XMLATTRIBUTES(t.department_name as "id", t.department_name as "name"),
                              (select XMLelement("employees",XMLAGG(XMLelement("employee",
                                                 XMLAttributes(g.employee_id as "id"),
                                                 XMlForest(g.employee_name as "employee_name")
                                                 ))) ---"employees" end
                                from TABLE(CAST(t.emp_tab as emp_ot)) g
                              ) ---end of inner select
                             )

                   )
                     from  TABLE(CAST(l_message as deps_t)) t
                        group by t.department_id)
                 ).getClobval() into l_xml_clob

from dual;


--  group by t.department_id;
--for rec1 in ( 
--select t.department_id||','
--       ||t.department_name||','
--       ||g.employee_id||','
--       ||g.employee_name||','
--       ||g.salary as r
--from  TABLE(CAST(l_message as deps_t)) t
--      ,TABLE(CAST(t.emp_tab as emp_ot)) g ) 
--      loop
----      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec1.department_id);
----      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec1.department_name);
----      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec1.employee_id);
----      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec1.employee_name);
----      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec1.salary);
--      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec1.r);
--      end loop;  
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_xml_clob);

END;
/
```

Comment: can you please delete the code we should not look at ? Thanks!

Comment: also please show us the error that you get because "Here I am facing problem" does not tells us much.

Comment: Not error. I am not getting the desired xml structure

Comment: So what is the problem ?

Comment: Please run the code you will understand.

Comment: I have already given the desired structure I am expecting.

Answer (score 0):

After many trials below code finally, givers expected output.

```
DECLARE 
  l_message DEPS_T;
  l_employee_t emp_ot;
  l_xml_clob CLOB;
BEGIN 
  SELECT deps_o(
           d.department_id,
           d.department_name,
           emp_ot(emp_o(
                        e.employee_id,
                        e.first_name || ' ' || e.last_name,
                        e.salary
                       )
                  )
           )
  BULK COLLECT INTO l_message 
  FROM   departments d , employees e
  where  e.department_id = d.department_id ; 

SELECT XMLELEMENT("Departments", 
       ( 
                SELECT   XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("department", 
                                            xmlattributes(t.department_id AS "id", t.department_name AS "name"),
                                            XMLELEMENT("employees",
                                                        XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("employee", 
                                                                 xmlattributes(g.employee_id AS "id"), 
                                                                 xmlforest(g.employee_name as "employee_name") ) ) 

                                                       )
                                            ))
                FROM     TABLE(cast(l_message AS deps_t)) t, 
                         TABLE(cast(t.emp_tab AS emp_ot)) g 
                GROUP BY t.department_id,t.department_name) ).getclobval() 
INTO   l_xml_clob 
FROM   dual;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_xml_clob);

END;
```